# Can Grid Index Features in ArcGIS Desktop fit over oddly shaped polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages

I am using ArcGIS 10.0 where I work.

One of the clients is wanting a map book as well as a locator map that shows where each page of the map is showing.  In order to do this I must first create an Index Grid with the Grid Index Feature tool.  Where I am running into trouble is the features associated with the shapefile are oddly shaped and vary in size.

Is there a way to make the grids fit over each feature in the shapefile?

Currently the Grid Index Feature tool only wants to give me boxes that fit over multiple and partial shapes.